# How to add View at real time to uninitialized Activity?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, oncreate

I run into a problem. The situation is that I have a launching activity called Home which contains a Tabhost(with four subtab). My application will receive real time message from remote server (like pubnub). When my application first start, only first tab is initialised, but when I receive a message, I want to add a view to some container in Tab2, which is not initialised until it get clicked. 
Is there any good solution to my problem or any pass by?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use Fragments.[Google's Sample Tutorial Link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)